# Logging Query Type in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to log the query type(DDL,DML,etc.) in the log, while logging the query trace in Rails. I achieved the query trace logging by patching ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber. But not able to get the query type. Can somebody help me in this?

P.S. I'm using Rails 4.